# R Reshape gives "Error: index out of bounds"

Tags: r, reshape

I have some data in a dataframe of the form:

```
projectID counter type
 1           1     C
 1           2     D
 1           3     C
 2           1     E
 2           2     C
 2           3     D
 2           4     C
```

I'm trying to use `reshape` to convert this to a dataframe of the form:

```
projectID 1  2  3  4 ...
 1        C  D  E  NA
 2        E  C  D  C
...
```

When I run

```
x <- reshape(x,timevar = "counter",idvar = "projectID",direction = "wide")
```

I get the error `Error: index out of bounds`.  I've found a couple of bug reports (which I don't really understand) but can't find anything on this issue. Very open to other ways to do the same thing. Note there are no NAs in the data, but there will of course be in the conversion to wide (because the 'counter' lengths are different for different projects).

Comment: Ah cool, I'd tried `x <- dcast(x, type ~ counter, paste)` before but obviously that's not quite what I'm looking for. Your answer works perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: Based on the data showed, `reshape(x,timevar = "counter",idvar = "projectID",direction = "wide")` worked

Comment: hm, there must be something in my actual data causing the error for reshape but not for the reshape2 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(x, projectID~counter, value.var='type')
#  projectID 1 2 3    4
#1         1 C D C <NA>
#2         2 E C D    C
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
spread(x, counter, type)
```